# Firestore: Save document ID into the Field

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Swift here and confused about how to save the document ID into itself field. Here is an example :

I have a collection named "menu"
[image: menu collection]

here we can focus on the one and only document in the "menu" collection which saved the name field "ayam goreng". How do i save the document ID "
7D3fuw3fri6oj287SySW" to the field named "menu_id" inside the document?

Comment: There should be a property on a given document reference that is the document id. You can use this value to update a property (called `menu_id` in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`:
>
> ```
> let newCityRef = db.collection("cities").document()
>
> // later...
> newCityRef.setData([
>     // ...
> ])
> ```

In your case, you can then [get the document ID from the new ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#documentid) with:

```
newCityRef.documentId
```